# TP Link TN-8200ND recognized but can't connect to network

Tags: 14.04

The device is recognized, I can view the networks, but I can't get to connect to wireless network, any help guys?

Comment: What have you tried? Give this a try and update your question with more specifics: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot/235280#235280

Comment: What about that question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/391981/tp-link-tl-wn8200nd-works-very-slowly

Answer (score 0):

Return it to the store, because the manufacturer's driver does not support connections to WiFi networks. I have the same situation.

Comment: You make it sound as if the manufacturer has a official driver for Linux **but** they support connections but not to Wifi networks... From what my short google search told me, there is no offical Linux support. Can you explain?

Comment: Manufacturer's driver supports access to hardware, so that you can see WiFi networks, may be do some other stuff, but it does not support connections to WiFi networks under Linux.