# Triyng to install driver for TP-Link USB adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers

I want to install the driver in [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391981/tp-link-tl-wn8200nd-works-very-slowly). I download, install and open up terminal to the directory and run `sudo bash install.sh` .

It works but gives me two errors. I think they are at the bottom of the setup.

```
    /home/joao/Desktop/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’) [enabled by default]
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
    make[2]: *** [/home/joao/Desktop/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [_module_/home/joao/Desktop/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
    make: *** [modules] Error 2
    ##################################################
    Compile make driver error: 2
    Please check error Mesg
    ##################################################
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: 14.04.3-desktop-amd64

Answer (score 0):

For kernel 3.19 you can install the driver this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

If you are offline, download these files

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192cu-dkms_0.2~trusty_all.deb

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb

Copy them to your Home directory and run

```
sudo dpkg -i rtl8192cu*.deb dkms*.deb linux-firmware*.deb
```

Comment: And how i do that with my desktop without internet? I have my laptop with ubuntu/windows 10 and internet.

Comment: I copied and run and said command not found : "sudo: dkms: command not found"

Comment: Oops. It was a typo. I will fix it in a sec.

Comment: Did install and rebooted and try to connect and says password authentication required asking for password and even after inserting password. im 100% sure password is correct.

Comment: So the adapter works. The connection issue is a different story. Maybe mac filter is used or something else is wrong.

Comment: I never have problems with many devices and computers so i almost sure its the OS.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but this driver should work OK.

Comment: And its wierd, i dont have any wired connection but says i had 1 used few minutes after booting pc.